# Manual for Stanford NLP Toolkit Parse

Tags: stanford-nlp

Where can I find the Stanford NLP dependency manual? Is it available online?

Answer (score 5):

The original manual can be found here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf

The general website for the parser is: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.html

A more specific page about the Neural Network Dependency Parser is: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.html

In the latest CoreNLP release, Stanford Dependencies have been replaced by Universal Dependencies as a default model. You can find documentation for this annotation schema on the [Universal Dependencies site](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/en/dep/index.html).